# ggplot will not plot missing category

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling with ggplot (I always do).  There are a number of *very* similar questions about forcing ggplot to include zero value categories in legends - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709451/display-all-factor-levels-in-ggplot-legend?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765710/force-ggplot-legend-to-show-all-categories-when-no-values-are-present) (for example).  BUT I (*think I*) have a slightly different  requirement to which all my mucking about with scale_x_discrete and scale_fill_manual has not helped.

**Requirement**: As you can see; the right-hand plot has no data in the TM=5 category - so is missing.  What I need is for that right plot to have category 5 shown on the axis but obviously with no points or box.

[image]

**Current Plot Script**:

```
#data
plotData <- data.frame("TM"    = c(3,2,3,3,3,4,3,2,3,3,4,3,4,3,2,3,2,2,3,2,3,3,3,2,3,1,3,2,2,4,4,3,2,3,4,2,3),
                       "Score" = c(5,4,4,4,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,5,5,4,4,5,4,5,4,5,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,3,5,5,5,5))
#vars
xTitle <- bquote("T"["M"])
v.I    <- plotData$TM
depVar <- plotData$Score

#plot
p <- ggplot(plotData, aes_string(x=v.I,y=depVar,color=v.I)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_jitter(alpha=0.8, position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0.2)) +
  geom_boxplot(width=0.75,alpha=0.5,aes_string(group=v.I)) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x=xTitle) +
  labs(y=NULL) +
  theme(legend.position='none', 
        axis.text=element_text(size=10, face="bold"),
        axis.title=element_text(size=16))
```

**Attempted Solutions**:

1. `drop=False` to scales (suggested by @Jarretinha [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834382/ggplot2-keep-unused-levels-barplot)) totally borks margins and x-axis labels

   `> plot + scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) + scale_fill_manual(drop=FALSE)`

[image]

2. Following logic from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765710/force-ggplot-legend-to-show-all-categories-when-no-values-are-present) and manually setting the labels in `scale_fill_manual` does nothing and results in the same right-hand plot from example above.

   `> p + scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green", "purple", "pink"),
                       labels = c("Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3", "Cat4", "Cat5"),
                       drop=FALSE)`
3. Playing with this logic and trying something with `scale_x_discrete` results in a change to category names on x-axis but the fifth is still missing AND the margins (as attempt 1) are borked again.  BUT apparent that `scale_x_discrete` is important and *NOT* the whole answer

   `> p + scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3", "Cat4", "Cat5"), drop=FALSE)`

[image]

**ANSWER** for above example courtesy of input from @Bouncyball & @aosmith

```
#data
plotData    <- data.frame("TM"    = c(3,2,3,3,3,4,3,2,3,3,4,3,4,3,2,3,2,2,3,2,3,3,3,2,3,1,3,2,2,4,4,3,2,3,4,2,3),
                       "Score" = c(5,4,4,4,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,5,5,4,4,5,4,5,4,5,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,3,5,5,5,5))
plotData$TM <- factor(plotData$TM, levels=1:5) # add correct (desired number of factors to input data)

#vars
xTitle <- bquote("T"["M"])
v.I    <- plotData$TM
depVar <- plotData$Score
myPalette <- c('#5c9bd4','#a5a5a4','#4770b6','#275f92','#646464','#002060')

#plot
ggplot(plotData, aes_string(x=v.I,y=depVar,color=v.I)) +
  geom_jitter(alpha=0.8, position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0.2)) +
  geom_boxplot(width=0.75,alpha=0.5,aes_string(group=v.I)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = myPalette, drop=F) +  # new line added here
  scale_x_discrete(drop=F) + # new line added here
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x=xTitle) +
  labs(y=NULL) +
  theme(legend.position='none', 
        axis.text=element_text(size=10, face="bold"),
        axis.title=element_text(size=16))
```

[image]

Comment: Notice in your first link that recommends `drop = FALSE`, the x variable is a factor.  Your x variable is currently numeric.  If you make it a factor and make sure it has all 5 levels of interest (e.g., `plotData$TM = factor(plotData$TM, levels = 1:5)`) you can use the answers you've linked to.

Comment: This is sort of an aside, but I'm very confused by `aes_string(x=v.I,y=depVar,color=v.I)`. `aes_string` is for passing the _names_ of columns in your data frame as strings, but you seem to be mapping raw numeric vectors, even though you passed the data frame in itself. Was that intentional?

Comment: @joran yup intentional.  To get a reproducable example I just copied the base script from my much larger .RMD script as these plots are being produced from dynamically created dataframes.  Make more sense?

Comment: @aosmith - I sussed the factors thing based on bouncyball's help below and it made ALL the difference!  Cheers

Comment: Sort of, except that it sort of makes your example a bit nonsensical. Because my first instinct was to recommend adding explicit factor levels as answered below, but doing that _in your data frame_ would actually **not** solve the problem in the example you presented because you have completely decoupled the data being plotted from your data frame. In the future, it would have been better to do `aes_string(x="TM",y="Score",color= "TM")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a workaround you could use:

```
# generate dummy data 
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(lets = sample(letters[1:4], 20, replace = T),
                  y = rnorm(20), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# define factor, including the missing category as a level
df1$lets <- factor(df1$lets, levels = letters[1:5])
# make plot
ggplot(df1, aes(x = lets, y = y))+
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = lets))+
    geom_point(data = NULL, aes(x = 'e', y = 0), pch = NA)+
    scale_fill_brewer(drop = F, palette = 'Set1')+
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Basically, we plot an "empty" point (i.e. `pch = NA`) so that the category shows up on the x-axis, but has no visible `geom` associated with it. We also define our discrete variable, `lets` as a `factor` with five levels when only four are present in the `data.frame`. The missing category is the letter `e`.

**NB**: You'll have to adjust the positioning of this "empty" point so that it doesn't skew your y axis.

Otherwise, you could use the result from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10835659/5619526) to avoid having to plot an "empty" point.

```
# generate dummy data 
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(lets = sample(letters[1:4], 20, replace = T),
                  y = rnorm(20), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# define factor, including the missing category as a level
df1$lets <- factor(df1$lets, levels = letters[1:5])
# make plot
ggplot(df1, aes(x = lets, y = y)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = lets)) +
    scale_x_discrete(drop = F) +
    scale_fill_brewer(drop = F, palette = 'Set1') +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: BEAUTY!  The trick was in factoring the x-axis categories (I was just assuming as integers it would all work) AND that NULL data trick - now I just have to roll this into the plot script to take account of whatever category is actually missing as sometimes its 1, sometimes 5.

Comment: By which it is really obvious.  When initialising the plotData df, as per @aosmith's comment just set the correct factor level for the xAxis data.  BINGO!